# for loop to add certain fields of an object in an arraylist

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Sorry if the title wasn't very clear.
anyways, I'm making a monopoly game and im currently working on the income tax space. I have an idea of how to make that, but what I'm stuck on is a method that is supposed to get the total value of all money, properties, etc.

Here's what i have so far:

```
public int getTotVal()
{
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.properties.size(); i++)
        tot += this.properties.get(i).mortgage;
    return tot;
}
```

The for loop is supposed to run through the ArrayList of properties, and for each property, add the mortgage value to the varialble "tot".

I know this isn't right, but how would i do it correctly?

*EDIT*

Player:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Player 
{
    private String name;
    private String token;
    public int wallet;
    private ArrayList properties;

    public Player(String name, String token, int wallet, Property prop)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.token = token;
        this.wallet = wallet;
        this.properties.add(prop);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the token
     */
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    /**
     * @param token the token to set
     */
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    /**
     * @return the wallet
     */
    public int getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }



    /**
     * @param wallet the wallet to set
     */
    public void setWallet(int wallet) {
        this.wallet = wallet;
    }

    /**
     * @return the properties
     */
    public ArrayList getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    /**
     * @param properties the properties to set
     */
    public void setProperties(ArrayList properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    //add buy()
    //add butProp()
    //add pay()
    //add payRent()

    public void pay(int amount)
    {
        this.wallet -= amount;
    }

    public int getTotVal()
    {
        int tot = 0;
        for (Property property : this.properties) 
        {
            tot += property.mortgage;
        }
        return tot;
    }
}
```

Property:

```
package monopolysrc;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Property extends Space
{
    private int value;
    private boolean owned;
    private int mortgage;

    public Property(String fn,String ln, int val, int mortgage, boolean owned)
    {
        super(fn,ln);
        val = value;
        owned = false;
        this.mortgage = mortgage;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public int getValue() {
    return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the owned
     */
    public boolean isOwned() {
        return owned;
    }

    /**
     * @param owned the owned to set
     */
    public void setOwned(boolean owned) {
        this.owned = owned;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mortgage
     */
    public int getMortgage() {
        return mortgage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mortgage the mortgage to set
     */
    public void setMortgage(int mortgage) {
        this.mortgage = mortgage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `return Tot;`, maybe ?

Comment: you have a spelling mistake. Tot rather than tot.

Comment: What makes you claim it isn't right?

Comment: I was going to do that eventually, there are other things i need to add, but i was wondering how to add the mortgage fields together in the for loop

Comment: what do you mean ? we need to see more code .can you show all of the class or classes ?

Comment: sure ill add the property class

Comment: I voted to close because this was "a simple typographical error. "

Comment: that wasnt the error, i changed the T to a t when i posted it but forgot to do it to the other Tot

Comment: I figured it out, i needed to state that the properties ArrayList was for property objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a neat way to loop over every element of a List:

```
for (Property property : this.properties) {
    tot += property.mortgage;
}
```

Comment: "Object cannot be converted to Property"

Comment: I figured it out, i needed to state that the properties ArrayList was for property objects

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public int getTotVal() {
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.properties.size(); i++)
        tot += this.properties.get(i).mortgage;
    return tot;
}
```

Comment: @vlatkozelka i forgot return, but i change Tot to tot, thanks.